# ggplot2 moving legend in to plot area without borders around key

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi im trying to add my legend area to my plot area without the white borders around my key. So far i have this:

Legend in plot area but white border present:

[image: legend1]

Legend style i want:

[image: legend2]

```
ggplot(data=Pig, aes(x=breed, y= p1_plus_p3_fat_depth_mm, color=sex))+
geom_boxplot()+
theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
xlab("Pig Breed") +
ylab("The P1 and P3 Fat Depth in mm")+
scale_colour_discrete(name  ="Sex",breaks=c("B", "S"),labels=c("Boar", "Sow"))+
theme(legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position = c(1, 1))+
theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"))
```

Comment: I don't see why the `legend.background` setting shouldn't work; the same thing with a different set of data is getting me something similar to your desired output. But without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), we can't see what might be going wrong

Comment: @camille Thankyou for your comment. The legend.background is making the otherwise white background transparent but its as if the borders around the keys are needing something else. Im very new to this, i dont know how to do a reproducible example, sorry. Thankyou for the the feedback

Comment: The link I posted has lots of suggestions for how to make an example it's easy to help with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `legend.key = element_blank()` to drop the background and borders around the boxplot icons.

```
ggplot(data=iris[c("Species", "Sepal.Length")], aes(x=Species, y= Sepal.Length, color=Species))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.position = c(1, 1))+
  theme(legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank())
```

[image]

I prefer using `element_blank()` which will remove a theme element as opposed to setting it to transparent and leaving it there. I've found depending on the graphics device the transparent can be interpreted differently.